# Editing now completely blocked while an edit is pending

Tags: bug, editing, review, suggested-edits

In [tags should be editable despite pending edit to text and vice versa](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6389), I noted that it was bad that one was being forced to review edits in order to be able to edit posts with a pending edit; but at that time at least one was able to review the edit and then go on to edit the post.

It appears that after a recent change a pending edit requires more than one review in order to be accepted (at least that had never happened to me before). This has aggravated the problem; now it's actually impossible to edit a post while an edit is pending. That is, an inexperienced user can block all editing by experienced users until a sufficient number of experienced users has taken the time to review her edit. The pending edit might relate to something trivial, and there might be something important to fix instead, e.g. serious vandalism, but it will be impossible to fix it, and there's nothing one can do except wait for others to decide to review the pending edit. This seems like a highly undesirable setup to me.

Comment: Relevant meta.SO thread: [It takes two to tango?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151536/it-takes-two-to-tango/) (Not much is said there, maybe the only interesting thing is a link to an older discussion about the problems they wanted to address by this change.)

Comment: In lieu of bounties on meta, I've added a tag to bump this question. This is very annoying and ought to be fixed.

Comment: @Lord_Farin, how would you like bounties to work on Meta?